# Fixing type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter project which is returning a list of data from an api in Json, I want to show the data as a list for a specific key which is name but currently I keep reciving:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Here is the future builder

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
 
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
 
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late Future<Workouts_Model> futureWorkouts;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureWorkouts = APIService.fetchUserWorkout();
  }
...................................
            FutureBuilder<Workouts_Model>(
              future: futureWorkouts,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data!.name ?? 'noname');
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) ;
                print(snapshot.error);
                {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
```

Here is the api_caller:

```
  static Future<Workouts_Model> fetchUserWorkout() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userWorkoutsAPI);
 
    final response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            'Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      },
    );
 
    final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(responseJson);
 
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Workouts_Model.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load User');
    }
  }
```

Here is the model:

```
import 'dart:convert';
 
List<Workouts_Model> workoutsModelFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Workouts_Model>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => Workouts_Model.fromJson(x)));
 
String workoutsModelToJson(List<Workouts_Model> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
 
class Workouts_Model {
  Workouts_Model({
    required this.id,
    required this.user,
    required this.name,
  });
 
  int id;
  String user;
  String name;
 
  factory Workouts_Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Workouts_Model(
        id: json["id"],
        user: json["user"],
        name: json["name"],
      );
 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "user": user,
        "name": name,
      };
}
```

How to show the list of `name` in the model so that I can see it when the application is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I see that the API will return multiple elements, then it's a `List` right?

in this line:

```
      return Workouts_Model.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

you're trying to assign a `List` to `Map<String, dynamic>`, which is wrong, you need to make a `List<Workouts_Model>` of the `List` of data in the API, so replace your method like this:

```
static Future<List<Workouts_Model>> fetchUserWorkout() async {
var url = Uri.parse(Config.apiURL + Config.userWorkoutsAPI);

final response = await http.get(
  url,
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
        'Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  },
);

final responseJson = jsonDecode();
print(responseJson);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return workoutsModelFromJson(response.body);
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load User');
}
}
```

then change this:

```
  late Future<Workouts_Model> futureWorkouts;
```

to this:

```
  late Future<List<Workouts_Model>> futureWorkouts;
```

then in your `FutureBuilder`:

```
   FutureBuilder<List<Workouts_Model>>(
          future: futureWorkouts,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Workouts_Model>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
               children: List.generate(snapshot.data!.length, (index) => Text(snapshot.data![index].name ?? 'noname')));
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) ;
            print(snapshot.error);
            {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation this makes a lot of sense but I am getting an error `error: A value of type 'Future<List<Workouts_Model>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<Workouts_Model>'. (invalid_assignment)`  because of this line `futureWorkouts = APIService.fetchUserWorkout();`

Comment: oh sorry, i will fix it

Comment: try now following steps again

Comment: i got ‘type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'’ but was not able to solve

Comment: can you tell me in which line you got this

Comment: This is the print(snapshot.error)

Comment: how should I debug this error to know from which line it is coming from?